# How to map a file which is located in a dll reference? ASP.NET AzureWebsites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

This is my project structure :

[image]

I want to access to `TemporaryFacturacion.pfx` from `XMLFactura` but all the ways the I've tried give me `"Invalid Route"`.

This is one of the ways the I tried :

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../../TemporaryFacturacion.pfx");
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path))
{
   fs.CopyTo(m);
}
```

Comment: It may caused by your path. You could change `../../` to `../` to have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, right click the .pfx file and select "**Properties**" then set the "Copy to Outpyt Directory" to "**Copy Always**". Refer to the following:

[image]

Then, you could use following code to get the full path of the .pfx.

```
string a = Path.GetFullPath("TemporaryFacturacion.pfx");
OR
string b= Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"TemporaryFacturacion.pfx");
```